# Proper way to spec JSON api

Tags: json, api, rest

I need to create CRUD json API for an entity that can be of two types.

If the entity is of 'type 1' then parameter_1 is always null and parameter_2 is an object of additional sub-parameters.

If the entity is of 'type 2' then parameter_1 is integer and parameter_2 is non-existent. My question is whether in this case it's a good practice to set parameter_2 to null, or set all sub-parameters to null instead? I'll give you an example below to be more specific.

'Type 1' object:

```
{
  name: 'object 1',
  parameter_1: null,
  parameter_2: {
      subparameter_1: 'somthing',
      subparameter_2: 'somthing else'
  }
}
```

Two ways of describing object of 'type 2':

```
{
  name: 'object 2',
  parameter_1: 123,
  parameter_2: null
}
```

or

```
{
  name: 'object 1',
  parameter_1: 123,
  parameter_2: {
      subparameter_1: null,
      subparameter_2: null
  }
}
```

Which one is preferable according to REST best practices? Thanks.

Comment: REST does not care. If your client and your server know what the values of `parameter_2` mean, both approaches are fine.

Comment: none of your examples contain valid json

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forcing two different 'schemas' into a single one. If you have no other constraints, consider splitting these into two different resources.